# Thickness of toprule and bottomrule when resizing table

Tags: tables, booktabs, resize

I have the problem that when my table gets too wide so that I have to resize it, the thickness of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` won't show any more. When I zoom in I can see that there still is a thickness variation between `\midrule` and the ones mentioned above. So I guess the thickness of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` is resized, too? Does anyone have a solution how one can resize a table AND have bold lines in the table?

```
\begin{table}[th]
\caption[Test]{Test.} \label{tab:Test}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccc} 
    \toprule
    {} & {TestTestTestTest} & {TestTestTestTest} & {TestTestTestTest} & {TestTestTestTest} & {TestTestTestTest} & {TestTestTestTest} & {TestTestTestTest} & {TestTestTestTest} \\
    \midrule
    {TestTestTestTest}  & \multirow{2}{*}{1000} & \multirow{2}{*}{1000} & \multirow{2}{*}{1000}  & \multirow{2}{*}{1000} & \multirow{2}{*}{1000} & \multirow{2}{*}{1000} & \multirow{2}{*}{1000} & {} \\[-2mm]
    {TestTestTestTest}  & {} & {} & {}  & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} \\       
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: only use `\resizebox` on tables at as a last resort and even then avoid doing it, there  are always better ways. use a smaller font eg `\small` or use column types like `p{2cm}` rather than `c` so the text in the cells can linebreak

Comment: Using `\resizebox` to make the tabular material “fit” inside the width of the textblock is taking the sledgehammer approach. Why worry about the thickness of some horizontal lines if everything else in the table has experienced the equivalent of being smashed to pieces?

Comment: note you have not provided a usable example so it is not possible to suggest a suitable font or line breaking strategy

Comment: also preventing the float going on a float page makes it _much_ more likely that that it goes to the end of the document.

Comment: This is the classical XY problem. What you should really ask is:  [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options)

Answer (score 3):

To long for the comment:

- You really need to consider all comments below your question.
- To solve your problem, you should consider to redesign your table. For example as shown in the following MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[th]
\caption[Test]{Test.} \label{tab:Test}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l XXX XXX XX}
    \toprule
    & Test Test Test Test   & Test Test Test Test   & Test Test Test Test 
    & Test Test Test Test   & Test Test Test Test   & Test Test Test Test 
    & Test Test Test Test   & Test Test Test Test   \\
    \midrule
TestTestTestTest  
    & \multirow{2}{*}{1000} & \multirow{2}{*}{1000} & \multirow{2}{*}{1000}  
    & \multirow{2}{*}{1000} & \multirow{2}{*}{1000} & \multirow{2}{*}{1000} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{1000} &                       \\
TestTestTestTest 
    &                       &                       &     
    &                       &                       &   
    &                       &                       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Above MWE is one of many possible solutions of your problem. Hopefully it will help you to rephrase your question and provide your MWE, which demonstrate your problem.